# Coloring a text part doesn't work (Python 3 + Sphinx html)

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I tried every solution i found but none of it works. Maybe cause of differences in Python 2 or 3, and/or older Sphinx version. This is what I have:

1. A Sphinx project with a seperated build and source directory
2. A file called custom.css which I placed in source/_static. Content:

```
    .blue {
        parent: bodytext;
        textColor: blue;
    }
```

3. I've edited my conf.py and added `html_css_files = ['custom.css']` below `html_static_path = ['_static']`
4. I've added `.. role:: blue` at the top of my *.rst document.
5. I've edited the file itself and wrote: This is a sentence with a :blue:`blue` word.

When I render my project the html source code contains: `This is a sentence with a <span class="blue">blue</span>` word.

All good except the fact the word isn't blue at all. It has the same color as the rest.

What am I missing?

Comment: When you build the docs, does the file `custom.css` get copied over to the build directory? Do you see any 404s for that file in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: Yes, it does. It lives in html/_static/custom.css. And as far as I can say there isn't any 404 in the dev tool section.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS syntax is incorrect. This should do it.

```
.blue {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: No, this and doesn't work either. Just tried (again). In the rendered source code it looks the same `<span class="blue">blue</span>`. Both variants probably can work, but doesn't here. I'm also using the standard Sphinx theme without any specialities.

Comment: Make sure that the `custom.css` in your build directory has the change I suggested and add `!important` (see edit), and that the file gets loaded by the browser. If that still doesn't do it, then use the inspector to determine what style is actually applied to that selector, and figure out how to override it.